# Contest a rejected edit for adding a link to the toolkit used in answer

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

If this is not the correct avenue for contesting rejected edits, *please tell me where to do so*.  Otherwise, **Please stop downvoting this question** as I am legitimately perplexed by reviewer's rationales.

I would like to contest a rejected [edit that I proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11734050).

It was rejected for

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

However, edit guidelines specifically include:

> ► add related resources or links

which is the crux of my edit, within text addressing the reader of the answer (not the author of the post).

It seems to me that the reviewers read over the edit a little too quickly.

Comment: (a) It's more than just a link and (b) "Hey, here's some background information I think someone else's answer should contain" really *does* belong in a comment. I would have rejected the edit, too, and of the available reasons when doing so, that's the closest to sensible.

Comment: How is that not improving the answer, though?  Trying to use the answer is confusing as hell without the tools installed, and that information really seems to belong up front, not as a comment.

Comment: IMO the edit is superfluous and I would have rejected it too with the same reason. Still IMO it should be a comment along the line 'Including a link to aws cli tools may improve this answer' (with the actual link inside). The main goal of the script is to explain the process, not to give a correct way to do it, as OP stated himself in his answer, adding a link to AWS cli is absolutely not needed for this answer, if it was peudo code it would not need any link.

Comment: @Tensibai But it **wasn't** pseudo code.  The answer is *only* usable *with* the AWS CLI toolkit installed.  Trying to use the answer without it installed is extraordinarily confusing, as one would expect an AWS-provided image to already have the toolkit included, but only one `ec2` command is in the (ubuntu) image by default.

Comment: @Randall that's where we disagree, the answer has not to be used As-is so don't need the link. The code is only to illustrate the steps.

Comment: @Tensibai Have you read the post (and comments)?  The author corrected typos in the code, and added additional checks (which are not needed if only using the code to demonstrate the concept of what needs to be done in the GUI).  He is clearly offering for the code to be used; the toolkit needs to be installed.

Comment: @Randall quoting the post itself: "The following bash script is not fit for production use, since it lacks any error-checking and it just uses sleep instead of polling to ensure AWS commands have completed.". Not having the link and needing to do some search about the commands involved is a sane thing for exactly this reasons. But again, this is just my opinion.

Comment: @Randall re 'as one would expect an AWS-provided image to already have the toolkit included', you may expect it, I don't. I personally expect my instances to **don't** have an infrastructure management toolkit available on them. Furthermore, the code has to be executed on a management box, not on the target box, OP never said a word about running this in another EC2 instance (even if it should be the safest way giving the box a role with proper permission and avoid using keys, but here we're slipping on another subject)

Comment: @algal As I'm particularly frustrated with my attempt to add a link to the AWS CLI for your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277733/restoring-a-volume-from-a-snapshot/18184239#18184239, I would love to get your take on this meta post.

Comment: Randall, regarding "Please stop downvoting this question": [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). You are not losing any rep.

Comment: Also, you may want to link to this meta post from that answer, as I don't see that user active on this post, so he may not see your @ ping...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks, on both counts - It really was not immediately apparent that voting was different (or how).  Still, particularly as my first meta post, all the downvotes have been incredibly alienating.

Comment: Suggested edits can be harshly reviewed, as reviewers may or may not have domain knowledge for the edited post. So diligent reviewers generally accept only the ones that look really obvious (fix dead link, spellings, etc). Whatever the outcome of this meta post, keep in mind that when you get to 2k, you will have full edit rights and you can make edits like the one in question without pushback.

Comment: I think @Randall's suggested edit is an improvement so let's put it in.

Answer (score 5):

**Don't** make such changes; your edit is an attempt to *reply*. In such cases, you should write it as a comment to the answer (see example in comments for this post).

OP is free to decide whether he wants it in *his* answer or not.

Comments are a very important part of every answer, so important ones are much appreciated and encouraged. But again, don't make significant changes to a post if it's not yours.

Comment: If you've not used the command line before, you'll need to [install and set up the AWS CLI tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-linux.html) before using the below commands.

Comment: I disagree - I'm not trying to reply, but prevent the next person from being confused when trying to implement the answer.  Additionally, IMO, links are poor in comments, as they can't be edited if/when the link changes.

Comment: @Randall Comments are part of the answer. Your comment will be noticed and considered (if it's outdated, you can add another comment). Who said you're not improving if you're posting it as a comment?

Comment: So, if I _just_ make "do it from the command line" (which is pre-existing text in the answer) a link to the _same_ page I was trying to link to, that's an acceptable edit?

Comment: @Randall I still prefer to suggest that in comments.. If you're sure OP is referring that link, and by mistake he posted a broken URL or an outdated one, I might consider edit the post and only fix the link..

Comment: There was no URL to begin with.  But I researched and found the link, installed, and verified it provides the commands used in the answer.

Comment: This entire answer and the comments below it are all wrong. OP is *not* free to decide what goes into their answer, this site is communally edited. It's built on a foundation of wiki-style editing. And comments below an answer are **not** "an important part of every answer". Comments are *temporary* things. They can be deleted at any point. If they contain important information, that information needs to be edited into the answer.

Comment: @meagar I don't agree that OP is *not* free to decide what goes into their answer. If you disagree with them, just downvote and write a comment - that's the best indication for others that something is wrong with the post. I won't like it if users edit my post and add references for things.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Assuming the edits did not conflict with the intent of your post and objectively improved it, you wouldn't have to like. The edits would be allowed. If you rolled back the edits and a moderator got involved, they would likely side with the person introducing the changes. This is and always has been a cornerstone of how edits work on this site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: @meagar But what if I think those changes are not good enough and I don't want to have them in my answer? *Improvement* in this case is a very subjective thing.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Then you'd probably roll he changes back, potentially triggering an edit war and moderator intervention. Again, *assuming the edits are actually good edits*, the moderator would generally side with the editor. Yes, it's a subjective call, but the entire point of having moderators is to *make* that subjective call.

Comment: @MarounMaroun "Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it."  It's really quite difficult to be substantial, and _not_ add something.  To me, it's a question of being **germane** and **in the spirit** of the answer, both of which I fully believe my suggested edit was.

Comment: @meagar There's a very fine line between *improvement* and *violation*, especially because improvement can be very subjective. That's why I don't like code changes, link changes (unless they're broken) and other significant changes.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The problem is that your answer states an author can reject edits to their answer because it's *their* answer, which is wrong. If the edit is otherwise good, the OP does not have this right. Yes, it's a very fine line, and there is no easy general solution, this is why moderators are empowered to arbitrate these situations.

Comment: @meagar [You've got the power](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BRv9wGf5pk)!